# Automatic calculation of cloudformation values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a Cloudformation template and in this template the customer selects the instance type they want according to the load. I wondered if there is something I can have this calculated automatically. For example, the user can just enter a value and based on that value the CF will automatically select the instance type. I can do this in Bash script etc but I wondered if there is a more accurate way.

Comment: "enter a value " - enter the value where, how? What bash script? Your question lacks details and is unclear.

Comment: You select instance type in CF template. I want to have this automatically selected according to the load. What is missing? I can write bash script and calculate it then write new cf template with new values and upload it easily. Did you get it ?

Comment: [Mappings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html). Apart from that CF is quite dumb and cannot calculate much.

Comment: Thanks @luk2302, It seems much more logical to have it calculated externally or to use AWS CDK.